# how can I change code in .twig in open cart theme

Tags: php, css, twig, opencart

I want change in code of open cart theme but all files is .twig so when I write php code in it don't work . until when i change in the stylesheet file . the theme don't see any changes.

how I can change .twig to php and make the theme see the changes in css file ??

this is part of header.twig

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>{{ title }}</title>
<base href="{{ base }}" />
{% if description %}
<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}" />
{% endif %}
{% if keywords %}
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ keywords }}" />
{% endif %}
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I want to add this code to it but when I put it in header.twig it don't work

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/style.css">
<?php if($direction=='rtl'){?>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/rtl-style.css">
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't mix PHP with TWIG. Just use passed variables. Check the documentation for more info:
https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29835

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/

Comment: You shouldn't use PHP or TWIG functions to detect RTL. That will invalidate your cache on every load and will affect your web performance. Instead use the "direction" property in CSS and add it to respective classes or ids.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to enable twig: https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=29835

Comment: I work on opencart 3 the files is already .twig 
my question is "how i can write php code in .twig ? " , thanks

Comment: you need to create Twig Extnesion, and include your PHP in it.

Comment: yes , but twig extension is already exist in opencart3 themes file .  I only want to change on it

Comment: You just need to register new function in twig extesnion, place in it your PHP code, then use that function in twig files.
Sample of twig ext: https://gist.github.com/merk/5259238